# How do I write data from python lists with various lengths of tuples inside to a file?

Tags: python, text

I have data coming from a function giving a tuple of x-y position of a circle, and then a single entry for the radius of a circle.  When I `print` the output of the function it gives me the output below, where the data is float:

```
((308.5, 221.0), 7.861134052276611)
```

How can I write this data to a file in a tab-delimited format, for example:

```
x1, "\t", y1, "\t", r, "\n"
```

If it's useful to you, the function I am working with is cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour).  I want to save my circle tracking data in a text file so that I can analyze it later.

Answer (score 2):

```
(x, y), r = ((308.5, 221.0), 7.861134052276611)
line = "{0}\t{1}\t{2}".format(x, y, r)

file_ = open("some.txt", "w")
file_.write(line)
```

You can then write a function for saving data to a file:

```
def save(data, filename):
    """
    Here data is a tuple with the form: ((x, y), r)
    """
    (x, y), r = ((308.5, 221.0), 7.861134052276611)
    line = "{0}\t{1}\t{2}".format(x, y, r)

    # Open the file with 'w+' mode in order to add the new lines
    # at the end.
    file_ = open(filename, "w+") 
    file_.write(line)
    file_.close()
```

If you use this function a lot, you might want to consider out the open-close-file code outside this function.

Comment: Perhaps clearer to use tuple unpacking: `(x, y), r = ((308.5, 221.0), 7.861134052276611)` and then `line = "{0}\t{1}\t{2}".format(x, y, r)`

Comment: Also, you can use the builtin csv module with ```delimiter='\t'``` for reading/writing the data file.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = ((308.5, 221.0), 7.861134052276611)

print '{0[0]}\t{0[1]}\t{1}'.format(*x)
```

result

```
308.5   221.0   7.86113405228
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
fileName.write("%f\t%f\t%f\n"%(tupleName[0][0],tupleName[0][1],tupleName[1]))
```

where `tupleName` contains the output of the function and `fileName` is your file object.

Comment: I think your format string is an overly-literal reading of the question.  I think he just means tab delimited.